# cmake - gflags.lib not opened

Tags: c++, cmake

I want to use [gflags](https://code.google.com/p/gflags/) with cmake for my program. i followed [this](https://gflags.googlecode.com/git-history/master/doc/gflags.html) tutorial, downloaded gflags, created the build folder, configured and generated it.

then, in the CMakeLists.txt for my program i added these lines:

```
find_package (gflags REQUIRED)
include_directories (${gflags_INCLUDE_DIR})
...
target_link_libraries (Program1 gflags)
```

Configuring and generating it with cmake throws no errors, the directory is set right (to the `gflags/build` folder)

but then, when i open my cpp (with VB11) and try to compile, it says that the file `gflags.lib` can not opened. I have only the main function in the cpp.

Do you know how can i fix this? I searched the gflags floder, but there i no such `gflags.lib` file.

Comment: That tutorial doesn't tell you how to build gflags.  You can't skip that step if you don't have a gflags.lib file available yet.

Comment: i downloaded the source code. if i don't build gflags, cmake does not find the gflags directory when i try to build my program